# Trying to create a regexp

Tags: java, python, regex

I have a string which I want a string to parse via Java or Python regexp:

```
something (\var1 \var2 \var3 $var4 #var5 $var6 *fdsfdsfd @uytuytuyt fdsgfdgfdgf aaabbccc)
```

The number of `var` is unknown. Their exact names are unknown. Their names may or may not start with "\" or "$", "*", "@" or "#" and there're delimited by  whitespace.

I'd like to parse them separately, that is, in capture groups, if possible. How can I do that? The output I want is a list of:

```
[\var1 , \var2 , \var3 , $var4 , #var5 , $var6 , *fdsfdsfd , @uytuytuyt , fdsgfdgfdgf , aaabbccc]
```

I don't need the java or python code, I just need the regexp. My incomplete one is:

```
something\s\(.+\)
```

Comment: why can't you just use a split method if they are just separated by whitespaces?

Comment: Java regexes are not good at capturing a variable number of some pattern.  I think you will have to use the regex you started with, add `()` to capture the part in parentheses like `something\s\((.+)\)`, extract the capture group into a string, then either `split` on the captured string or do something else to loop on that string.  But you can't do what you want with a single regex, at least in Java. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`something\s\((.+)\)`

In this regex you are capturing the string containing all the variables. split it based on whitespace since you are sure that they are delimited by whitespace.

```
m = re.search('something\s\((.+)\)', input_string)
if m:
    list_of_vars = m.group(1).split()
```

Comment: I don't know Python, but in Java this wouldn't work because you haven't defined any capture groups.  You'd need an extra set of parentheses in the regex.  Does Python work differently in this regard?

Comment: I've just checked and it said it had only one group which is the initial string `something (\var1 \var2 \var3 $var4 #var5 $var6 *fdsfdsfd @uytuytuyt fdsgfdgfdgf aaabbccc)`

Comment: @ajb, thanks. Just copy pasted the OP's regexp though I had made the change in the trial code I had written. I have made an edit.

Comment: @Dett, Can you try now?